# Weird library behavior with DCMTK

Tags: c++, macos, dcmtk

I'm facing a weird problem concerning the deployment of my software.

I have compiled a library for opening Dicom files with *DCMTK* in the backend. Also linked in are *Qt5* and a tiny fraction of the Boost libs.
When I use the library on my System, everything just works fine, as it does on the systems of the other developers in the team.

Now it comes to the deployment. Since the frontend uses Python, I created a wrapper (Boost Python) around the library, and again everything works just fine. However, as soon as I transfer the library to another system (the same Mac OS X system as I use for developing, i.e, same Mac, same OS version) things start to get weird.

I can open the DICOM set, except one: Hereby, the DCMTK part of the library complains that it cannot find reasonable values (`.bad()` delivers `true`) on opening various DicomTags and indeed, most values are 0 or the respective max value. 
When the same colleague with the same system compiles the library from scratch, everything works just fine.

To create the library I first link my sources against *DCMTK* to create a state library. This is then linked against the Boost Python Module which is a shared library.

I hope someone has an idea where I could search, since I'm quite lost here.

How can it be that the same library produces different results on the same system? Somehow I think, the compilation step changes something, but I don't know where to look.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be: Did you make sure that the DICOM data dictionary is actually loaded (if not built into the library)? This could be done from your program by calling dcmDataDict.isDictionaryLoaded().

For details, see the documentation: http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/file_datadict.html